# Can create new model instance but can not update an existing one oin Django

Tags: django, django-admin

For some reason i can create an new instance of classified model but cannot update an existing one neither via my view or through admin panel in Django. I am using postgresql and from the logs, it seems like queries are not hitting the database at all. I removed and resetted the app, even drop the tables but didn't help.

```
class classified(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=True, null=True)
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    point = models.PointField(srid=settings.SRID, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True, null=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    submission_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        #return "%s %s %s"%(self.title, self.point.x, self.point.y)
        return "%s"%(self.title)
    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('listing_detail', (),
                    {
                        'slug' :self.slug,
                    })

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        if not self.point:
            location = "%s+%s+%s+%s"%(self.address, self.city, self.state, self.zipcode)
            cord = get_lat_long(location)
            x,y = cord.split(",")
            x = float(x)
            y = float(y)
            self.point = Point(x,y)
            self.point2 = Point(x,y)
            super(classified, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

ClassifiedImage model:

```
class ClassifiedImage(models.Model):
    classified = models.ForeignKey(classified, related_name="images", null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='classifieds/%Y/%m/%d',  default='static/img/no-thumb.jpg', null=True, blank=True)
```

Classified View:

```
def add_classified(request):
    userprofile = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = classifiedForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            classifiedad = form.save(commit=False)
            image_formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=classifiedad)
            classifiedad.submitted_by = request.user
            classifiedad.save()
            image_formset.save()
            slug = classifiedad.slug
            redirect_to =reverse('classified-detail', kwargs={'slug':slug})
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
    else:
        form = classifiedForm()
        image_formset = ImageFormSet()
    return render_to_response('shclassified/add_classified.html',{'form':form, 'image_formset':image_formset},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Classified Update view:

```
def ClassifiedUpdate(request, slug):
    classifiedins = classified.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = classifiedForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            #classifiedad = form.save(commit=False)
            image_formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix="images", instance=classifiedins)
            #classifiedad.submitted_by = request.user
            #classifiedad.save()
            #form().save()

            image_formset.save()
            #slug = classifiedad.slug
            return HttpResponseRedirect(".")
    else:
        form = classifiedForm(instance=classifiedins)
        image_formset = ImageFormSet(instance=classifiedins, prefix="images")
    return render_to_response('shclassified/add_classified.html',{'form':form, 'image_formset':image_formset},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: you are missing `image_formset.is_valid()`

Comment: Also, the reason update is not working is, you need to send the instance to the `request.POST` too: `form = classifiedForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=classifienins)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding the `save` method incorrectly by the looks of things:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    if not self.point:
        location = "%s+%s+%s+%s"%(self.address, self.city, self.state, self.zipcode)
        cord = get_lat_long(location)
        x,y = cord.split(",")
        x = float(x)
        y = float(y)
        self.point = Point(x,y)
        self.point2 = Point(x,y)
    super(classified, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  ## wrong indentation!
```

Your `super()` call should be aligned with the first level of indentation. As you have it, `super().save` is only called if there is no `self.point`.

Comment: Thank you now i am able to update it the models at least at the Django admin. But it looks like I still need to fixed the update view.